# How to plot an affinity cluster using scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am clustering some names using scikit's AffinityPropogation and I want to plot/visualize the clusters. My input data has precomputed proximity and this is what it looks like:

```
#sample input data
joe,mike,ali,andrew,sean
.2,.221,.5,.5,.7
.82,0,.1,.72,.0
.7,.88,.7,.2,1
0,0,.4,.8,.9
.3,.03,.07,.003,.2
```

And here is the simple code i have in place for clustering:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.cluster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import metrics

data = pd.read_csv('/pydata/nametokenmatrix.txt')

M = data.as_matrix()
af = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
af.fit(M)

cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
labels = af.labels_
```

On running this code, i do generate some clusters but I'm unsure how to plot this so that I can visualize them. Since I'm kicking the tires with clusterization, I want to compare different algorithms by plotting them. Something like [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html).

Thanks

Comment: What is the dimensionality of your data points, i.e the shape of M?

Comment: it's shape is roughly 60000 x 60000. Where  each name is a column and each row is the precalculated distance of the row with each col\name. I've included a sample data snippet in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to embed your affinity matrix.

A carefully adapted non-metric MDS should be a good start.